# Erro ao enviar aplicativo para App Store Connect

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, apple, xamarin.ios

Sou novato no assunto e estou tentando carregar aplicativo em Xamarin Forms para Apple Store Connect mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao meu entender meu SDK está na versão 15.4 e preciso atualizar para versão 16.1. Como é feito essa atualização no visual studio?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]